# can you help me, i dont understand

Tags: php

> Warning: require_once(pages/admin.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\bisnis\config\init.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'pages/admin.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bisnis\config\init.php on line 6

```
<?php
    session_start();

    //load class
    spl_autoload_register(function($class){
        **require_once 'pages/' .$class. '.php';**
    });
    $user = new user();
    $admin = new admin();


?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Like the error says. Your file `pages/admin.php` doesn't exist. It's probably looking in the wrong folder. Note that the require once is being called from your init.php script so it's currently looking for `C:\xampp\htdocs\bisnis\config\pages\admin.php`. It's probably not in that folder. You can start your `require_once` with a `/` to indicate that it should start looking from the root folder or use `../` to "go up" a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to find the file `pages/admin.php` in the `C:\xampp\php\PEAR` directory, which is on the include path.
What I would probably do is to provide the absolute path form within the `spl_autoload_register` - something along these lines:

```php
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $path = realpath(implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [
        __DIR__,
        'pages',
        $class.'.php'
    ]));
    require_once($path);
});
```

Make sure that you point to the correct directory - by just using `__DIR__` constant it will assume your `pages` directory is within the same directory as this autoloading file.

If you have it one level up, create your path as:

```php
$path = realpath(implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [
    __DIR__,
    '..',
    'pages',
    $class.'.php'
]));
```